# Does $E(|f_n(S)-f(S)|)\rightarrow 0$ show almost sure convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n(S)$ be a sequence of random variables, and $f(S)$ a random variable. Does the identity:

$$\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(|f_n(S)-f(S)|)=0$$

show almost sure convergence of $f_n(S)\rightarrow f(S)$.

I am wondering as it is certainly the case that:

$$E(|X-Y|)=0$$

shows that almost surely $X$ and $Y$ are the same. But does similar work for sequences?

Comment: $E(|X_n-X|) \to 0$ is called $L^1$ convergence, this is not equivalent to a.s. convergence. Note sure I understood the $f_n(S)$ and $f(S)$ notation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. On $(0,1)$ consider the indiactor functions of the intervals $[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}}, \frac {i-1} {2^{n}})$ arrange in a sequence. This sequence converges in mean but does not converge at any point.

Comment: what if the variable is bounded by integrable variable? Also, I believe the interval is not the intended one.

Comment: The sequence of random variables I am considering are bounded by the constant $1$ which is integrable. @Dole